# phpmyadmin doesn't allow import / export fiiles

Tags: phpmyadmin

i am using phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 18.04 and php7.3 , when i try to import or export file it shows me this error :

> Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
>    count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
>   so i went to this file (plugin_interface.lib.php) and tried to cast $options to array, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You reported https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14777

It was fixed in 4.6.6

Please try latest version